# How to create simple command line UI like the debian installer?

Tags: linux, colors, console, installation, debian

[Here's a screenshot of the debian installer](http://www.remoteresponder.net/img/blog/squeeze_ssh_install_07.png)

Can I use this with a simple command line command?
like:

```
sth --size 20x20 --title 'Debian Installer' --text 'I'm a Text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the `whiptail` command, if you only want to write a shell script (as the debian installer is).

There is a good page of it in the Bash Shell Scripting Book on WikiBooks:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail

Answer (score 0):

Its made with [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Most commonly used with C, altough you can get bindings for it to use with python, perl and alike.